TP5100 for 8.4/4.2V 1S and 2S Lithium Battery Charger Schematic
I am trying to use TP5100 for 2S (3v7 serial 3v7) charging. This is my Schematic, it's basic copy on Typical Application but have a little difference. I'm not sure whether it works or I draw wrong at somewhere, can I need help??

[Typical Application From Datasheet ][2]
[Another typical application][3]

Nguyễn Thị Minh Hiếu - Hi, You included links to images which are not yours. To comply with the site rule on referencing, details of the original source of copied / adapted material must be provided by you, next to each copied / adapted item. If the original source is online & public, please [edit] the question & add the webpage/PDF name & its link (URL) (e.g. website name + webpage title + its URL). (Just saying an image came from gg (Google?) is not enough. Google is an index only. Please link to the original source webpage (HTML) which displayed each copied image. TY)
